Syntax error for simply creating and using database in DBeaver
Note: I am not an experienced developer by any means! please be kind.
I am trying to get a simple web development setup to work so I can work on a webapp. I have a few docker containers running for MariaDB, PHP-fpm and Nginx. Right now I can edit and see PHP pages on my localhost in my browser. The PDO connection to MariaDB also works. I installed DBeaver and used it to connect to my MariaDB Docker container, to work on my create and insert scripts for my MariaDB database.
It went well so far, last week I made my first create script and it worked just fine. I tried it again today and suddenly it's full of errors that I can't figure out. Nothing seems to work. I don't think it can be a regular syntax error because I do everything the MariaDB syntax tells me to do in their documentation. I've been trying to solve this for a few hours now and I am getting really frustrated.
This is my create script (changed the names for the sake of anonymity and didn't put the other tables in because the error is somewhere between the first three commands anyway):
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS db_name;

CREATE DATABASE db_name;

USE db_name;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tablename 
(
    pk_number INT(5) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    column1 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    column2 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    column3 VARCHAR(30),
    column4 VARCHAR(30),
    column5 VARCHAR(10),
    column6 VARCHAR(6),
    column7 VARCHAR(20),
    column8 DATE
);

When I run the SQL Script it says:

SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn=19) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'USE db_name;
CREATE TABLE tablename (
pk_number VARCHAR(30) PRIMAR...' at line 2
Error position: line: 1

Or:

SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn=18) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'USE db_name' at line 3

I can't figure out whether the problem is:

With the drop or replace database command
With the USE database command
With the create table script
With DBeaver or something

I thought maybe try something different, so I tried to run this:
CREATE OR REPLACE DATABASE db_name;

USE db_name;

CREATE TABLE tablename 
(
    column1 VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
    column2 VARCHAR(30)
);

This gave the same result. I don't know why I can't 'USE db_name'??
I also tried some other things like:

`backticks around the table names
'these ticks' around the table names
USE DATABASE instead of USE
Drop and create the database by hand and then run the USE and CREATE TABLE script (same result)
Deleting all of the whitespace
Uncommenting and deleting unnecessary text

The weirdest thing is that it all works fine if I run the queries individually (so first run drop database, then run create database, then run create table).
Why is this happening? What can I do about it?
I wonder if maybe the database doesn't realise that it's made the database and then concludes that it isn't able to use that database? I don't know how to explain that really but I used to put "GO" in between lines when I used Microsoft SQL and that used to help but I can't use that here obviously.
Any help or tips are appreciated! Thanks for reading.
And before you comment: yes, I actually have checked tons of similar questions and they were not helpful at all! I've used google and asked friends and that also didn't help me (that's why I am making a post).

Hi - try running each statement individually in turn. Then you’ll know which statement is actually causing the issue and you can debug just that one

@NickW Thanks for your reply. I tried running them all individually, and they all work when I do that. So then why doesn't it work if I run them all at the same time?
it says:
"SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn=18) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE DATABASE db_name;
USE db_name;
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tablename(
pk_...' at line 2
Error position: line: 1"

So run the first two, does that error? If not run the first three, does that error? Etc. You’ll then know where the issue is

"..... please be kind"  we, on stackoverflow.com, are always kind

@NickW It happens as soon as I put the first and second one together, so the "USE db_name;" part. Why? I really can't figure out what could be wrong with that

Please add the IF NOT EXISTS to your CREATE DATABASE statement. (Because it only needs to be created when it does not (yet) exists)

@Luuk I just changed it to "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS", still the same issue. :(

@Luuk I also tried to work around that whole problem by using "CREATE OR REPLACE DATABASE" but that has the same result, it gives an error on the "USE database" statement

It might be this bug?: Not able to execute use [database] statement, which version of DBeaver are you using? (NOTE 24.0.4 is not release yet!, you need to wait till May 6th )

Until then, you might be able to use the workaround a user mentioned here at Luuk's link reference.

Which MariaDB version are you using? (select version(); will tell you.)

The USE Database is a newer syntax in MariaDB that may be causing issues with your versions of MariaDB or DBeaver. Try it with just USE

@Luuk yes it was this bug! They have since released a new version and it seems to have solved the problem if I run the entire script! (if I run only a part of it it still gives me the error)

Okay nevermind, it was helpful for like 5 minutes and now I get the same error again...

Why are you using CREATE OR REPLACE, (and not just CREATE) ?  The database should  be empty, it was just created ....  (I am trying to reproduce this, in MySQL...)

@Luuk good question, I guess if the database was really dropped, using CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE is unnecessary. Update: I rolled back to DBeaver 24.02 and my script now works fine as long as I use "execute script". I think the new update didn't completely fix the problem

Can you share the info from SELECT version(); ?

Ok, I tested using DBeaver 24.0.4, and i cannot reproduce the problem  (I just realized that I also had an 11.3.2-MariaDB-1:11.3.2+maria~ubu2204 installation on my NAS ).  When you say "works fine as long as I use "execute script"", I started to re-read the question, but it is unclear (to me) why you do want to do anything other than execute script (ALT+X)

@Luuk I am currently in version 11.3.2-MariaDB-1:11.3.2+maria~ubu2204, which has solved my issues.

@Luuk yeah I tried running "execute query" with multiple lines selected before but that still gives me errors, figured that was probably not the right way to use it and now I use execute script while selecting the lines, which works ;) (but only in the older version of DB)
